# Huffman Encoding of "digitale bildverarbeitung"

Tags: tree, character-encoding, huffman-code

I have the input "digitale bildverarbeitung". I have to build the tree using Huffman's algorithm. I then have to encode data using the Huffman codes in order to write it. For example:

```
100001111100011100001111100010010
```

I built the tree, giving these codes for each character:

```
  11000
a 1011
b 1001
d 1010
e 011
g 1000
i 00
l 010
n 11011
r 1110
t 1111
u 11001
v 11010
```

I need to write the data in binary, but i don't understand how.
Can someone help?

Comment: Using your translation dictionary `{' ': '11000', 'a': '1011', 'b': '1001', 'd': '1010', 'e': '011', 'g': '1000', 'i': '00', 'l': '010', 'n': '11011', 'r': '1110', 't': '1111', 'u': '11001', 'v': '11010'}`, the text `digitale bildverarbeitung`  translates to Huffman code `1010001000001111101101001111000100100010101011010011111010111110100101100111111001110111000`. On the other hand, your Huffman code `100001111100011100001111100010010` encodes to text `geririerib` (if removed the harmful trailing zero).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the Huffman codes for each character in the string. `digi` becomes `101000100010`.